# jQuery Masonry.js not formatting correctly; what is the issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

It looks like I'm doing everything alright; however, all the posts seem to just appear in rows equal to the height of the tallest image in that row.

1234
1200
0200
5678
5008

as opposed to

1234
1256
7258
0008

That picture may not make much sense so I've included a screenshot...

http://i.imgur.com/Sj2i7EX.png

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Masonry Testing</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/main.css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="grid">    
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          $("#grid").masonry({
            itemSelector: ".grid-item"
          });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$.getJSON(
  "http://www.reddit.com/r/pics.json?jsonp=?",
  function foo(data)
  {
    $.each(
      data.data.children.slice(0, 50),
      function (i, post) {

        $("#grid").append( "<div class='grid-item'>" );
        $("#grid").append( "<img src='" + post.data.url + ".jpg' />" );
        $("#grid").append( "<div class='post-title'>" + post.data.title +"</div>" );
        $("#grid").append( "<div class='post-info'>");
        $("#grid").append( "<div class='upvotes'>
                            <span><i class='fa fa-arrow-up'></i> " + 
                            post.data.ups + "</span></div>" );
        $("#grid").append( "<div class='comments'>
                            <span><i class='fa fa-comments'></i> " + 
                            post.data.num_comments + "</span></div>" );
        $("#grid").append( "<div class='sourcebtn'><span>View on Reddit</span></div>" );
        $("#grid").append( "</div>" );
        $("#grid").append( "</div>" );

      }
    )
  }
)
```

My JavaScript code works fully -- the formatting is made silly because StackOverflow wants my code more neat than I tend to have it.

My question mainly is: **Where's the error with Masonry.js? Why won't it properly stack segments?**

Comment: Why do you have all that white space in your link to the masonry CDN?  Whitespace is interpreted in URLs.  Try removing all the white space.  It looks like it's just not loading masonry.

Comment: You're not appending things correctly. You can't append half a `<div>`. (e.g., `$("#grid").append( "</div>" );` does nothing).

Comment: Blah, I am correct in my actual document. But every time I post code on StackOverflow that cause horizontal scrolling, I get told to edit it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that `jQuery(document).ready()` is firing before the `$.getJSON` asynchronous request has finished, so Masonry is being activated on an empty `div`. I would try moving your Masonry initialization code to the end of your `$.getJSON` callback:

```
$.getJSON(
  "http://www.reddit.com/r/pics.json?jsonp=?",
  function foo(data)
  {
    $.each(
      data.data.children.slice(0, 50),
      function (i, post) {
        // Add your divs
      }
    )
    $("#grid").masonry({
      itemSelector: ".grid-item"
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Amazing. This was it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`.append(html)`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function works differently than how you are using it. For example:

```
$("#grid").append( "<div class='grid-item'>" );
// Step 1: Find `#grid` element
// Step 2: Convert "<div class='grid-item'>" to DOM Elements
// Step 3: Append new DOM Elements to `#grid` element
```

So doing the following:

```
$("#grid").append("<div>");
$("#grid").append("<img src='someurl'>");
```

Will result in

```
<div></div>
<img src='someurl' />
```

Instead of

```
<div>
    <img src='someurl' />
</div>
```

One solution is to simply write your append as one statement:

```
$("#grid").append( 
    "<div class='grid-item'>"
    + "  <img src='" + post.data.url + ".jpg' />"
    + "  <div class='post-title'>" + post.data.title +"</div>"
    + "  <div class='post-info'>"
    + "    <div class='upvotes'>"
    + "      <span><i class='fa fa-arrow-up'></i> " 
    +          post.data.ups 
    + "      </span>"
    + "    </div>"
    + "    <div class='comments'>"
    + "      <span><i class='fa fa-comments'></i> " 
    +          post.data.num_comments 
    + "      </span>"
    + "    </div>"
    + "    <div class='sourcebtn'><span>View on Reddit</span></div>"
    + "  </div>"
    + "</div>" );
```

Comment: You're right. But I had pasted a prior copy of my code by mistake. Apologies. Thanks anyway.